# SVN Change a file during branch

Tags: svn

Let's say I have script.py.  When I'm branching this using `svn copy` I want to append a line to the top of the file.

Is this possible to do?  Or can it not be done?

So

```
svn copy -rHEAD file:///svn/repo/trunk/script.py file:///svn/repo/branches/script.py
(Add line to the top of the branched file)
svn commit -m "Branching script.py"
```

Should be easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flavour of `svn copy` you have chosen will do the copy from one repository location to another repository location atomically. In that case your `svn commit` is not necessary.

You have two choices:

1. Branch, checkout (or `switch`) modify the script, checkin, OR
2. Modify script in your workingcopy and do `svn copy . $DEST_URL`. This will take the state of your working copy and create a new branch for you.

More automation is not possible in a clean way, because modifying hook scripts on the repository/server side are considered evil by the Subversion developers.

Comment: I've looked into hooks and they are pretty horrid, hens why I want to do it this way.  The problem with checking in and out is I want this to be usable my multiple users, so the only "known" directory structure is the repo.  Might have to reconsider how I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prepend when adding lines to the beginning of a file. From http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-prepend-text-lines-to-file/:

```
echo "My New Line"|cat - yourfile > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out yourfile
```

Comment: You can't open file:///svn/repo/trunk/script.py